# JS как передать значение div из одно в другой div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня не получается правильно передать значение из одного div в другой div
Мне нужно из блока .prime - перенести значение в .result

А у меня передается почему то значение кнопки, как исправить ?

Мой код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
    $(".result").text('')
    $(".result").append($(this).html())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prime" ><span>div1</span></div>
<div class="button">click</div>

<span class="result"> this </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, вам нужно что-то такое:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function() {
      $(".result").html($(".prime").html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prime" ><span>div1</span></div>
<div class="button">click</div>

<span class="result"> this </span>
```

Comment: супер, спасибо :)